# Python: For loops print only last element of a list

Tags: python, php, for-loop, exec

I am using a shared webspace and I can't install the dotenv libiary for php, but I can use the dotenv libiary for python to call enviorment variables from outside of my public directory and I also set the basedir for php, so that php can't access my `.env` file directly.

To call my `.env` file with the secret keys, I run a bash.sh over the php function 'exec' and that bash.sh script calls/runs my python script to load the `.env` file. That works fine.

But now, I want to print out all available enviorment varaibles through the python code with a for loop and I always just got the last element of the list.

I also created a simple python test script, put it on my server and I got the same issue.

**PHP-File:**

```
echo exec("./bashENV.sh", $error);
```

**bashENV.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod +x ./testENV.py
python ./testENV.py
```

**testENV.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
nums = [1 ,2, 3]
for num in nums:
    print(num)
```

If I run the python script on my local pc, it prints out 1,2,3. But on my shared webspace I only got the 3. It runs python 2.7.13 on the webserver and I can't install version 3.

Does anyone know, what is wrong with my code? Why the script prints only the last element?

Comment: @AbraCadaver That's an error. I believe you mean `print(str(num) + "\n")` or something similar. And `print` already prints a newline.

Comment: I have no idea if this would be caused by buffering, but try changing your python line in the bash script to `python -u ./testENV.py`. Are you sure though that the 1 and 2 aren't just up in the history a bit? It's weird for leading elements to be dropped; especially when newlines are being printed as well.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I change the print line into `print(str(num) + "\n")` and now, there is no more any output at all. I also change the line in the python script into `python -u ./testENV.py`, but nothing change. It still prints out only the last element '3'.

Answer (score 0):

Using `exec` like this will always print the last line of output generated by the shell command. In your example, each line of the output generated by your python script will be stored in your `$error` variable (you have `$error` in the `$output` [position](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) ). If you would prefer the output stored as one big string, you might try [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)